# Multiple choice equivalent for conditional (ternary) operator?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I have this side obsession of making my Java code more terse. With reason, of course: the more I see on one screenfull, the easier it becomes to follow the logic.

For instance, when assigning values, one might write:

```
String result;
if (arg != null) {
   result = arg.toString();
} else {
   result = "default";
}
```

but of course this is much shorter:

```
String result = (arg != null) ? arg.toString() : "default";
```

However, for an non-boolean condition (i.e., more than 2 choices), one is still stuck with the `switch` statement, e.g.:

```
SimpleDateFormat format;
switch (dateOrder) {
case DMY :
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("{2}" + sep + "{1}" + sep + "{0}");
    break;
case MDY :
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("{1}" + sep + "{2}" + sep + "{0}");
    break;
case YMD :
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("{0}" + sep + "{1}" + sep + "{2}");
    break;
default :
    format = null;
}
```

I have come up with a utility class that uses generics, lambdas, and the chaining paradigm to give a syntax like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = Multary.<DateOrderEnum, SimpleDateFormat>nSwitch(dateOrder)
        .nCase(DateOrderEnum.DMY, () -> new SimpleDateFormat("{2}" + sep + "{1}" + sep + "{0}"))
        .nCase(DateOrderEnum.MDY, () -> new SimpleDateFormat("{1}" + sep + "{2}" + sep + "{0}"))
        .nCase(DateOrderEnum.YMD, () -> new SimpleDateFormat("{0}" + sep + "{1}" + sep + "{2}"))
        .nDefault(() -> null)
        .result();
```

(The class itself is fairly easy to implement so I won't bore readers with that code.)

My questions are:

1. Am I reinventing the wheel here? Judging by search results, I'm not the only one with this itch to scratch. Has something similar been done previously?
2. Any downsides to this? A few that I can think of include:

   - Possible inefficiency, due to using a `Map` internally instead of a language construct;
   - No compiler warnings to warn of unused constants (as would be in the case of a `switch` with an `enum`) - problems (including "no suitable case as well as no default case supplied") can only be detected at runtime, with a suitable exception being thrown;
   - There is also no compiler checking of duplicate constants or multiple defaults - the most recent call will be definitive. This can again be checked only at runtime (with a suitable exception being thrown);
   - Forgoing the "fall through" capability of `case` statements - each `nCase()` call works with exactly one constant (although this *could* be ameliorated with some more code... which might clutter the syntax more);
   - Code autoformatting *could* mess the chained commands up to an unreadable chaos, so care is needed to set it up satisfactorily.

Comment: This question is likely off topic as very opinion based. That said, seeing more on one screen is not the ultimate goal of programming. You are massively sacrificing readability and semantics for fewer characters. For anyone except you (and possibly you when you go back to review your code in a few weeks, months, years) this will be much more difficult to follow.

Comment: There are lots of cleaner ways to do this, though frankly I don't buy that this is nicer than the `switch`.  Using an `EnumMap` from `DateOrderEnum` to `SimpleDateFormat`, perhaps, or to `String`s that specify that format except for the separator.  Providing this as a method on the enum directly.

Comment: @CollinD: agree that it is probably very opinionated. I guess opinions about readability will also differ widely :-) I'll add a close vote.
@LouisWasserman: the selector may not always be an enum, sometimes another object may be needed. Also, mapping to a `Supplier<ResultType>` instead of to values of `ResultType`, might be more memory and performance efficient (just guessing: calculations do not need to all be done upfront and stored). Which brings me back to my impl.
Thanks for your opinions though, even if I may not agree with them, I do have to figure out why, and that is valuable to me.

Answer (score 5):

You can always chain the three way conditional operators:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = 
  dateOrder == DMY ?
    new SimpleDateFormat("{2}" + sep + "{1}" + sep + "{0}")) :
  dateOrder == MDY ?
    new SimpleDateFormat("{1}" + sep + "{2}" + sep + "{0}")) :
  dateOrder == YMD ?
    new SimpleDateFormat("{0}" + sep + "{1}" + sep + "{2}")) :
  null;
```